# Conforming Rails form into Formtastic Equivalent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I have a Rails application where I am using Active Admin as the backend. Active Admin uses Formtastic and I am having trouble converting one of the input fields in my _form.html.erb for posts.

Here is the form...

```
<div class="container">
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :author %>
    <%= f.collection_select :blog_id, Blog.all, :id, :name, prompt: "Select a blog" %>        
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <p>
      Categories:<br>
      <%= hidden_field_tag "post[category_ids][]", nil %>
      <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
        <%= check_box_tag "post[category_ids][]", category.id, @post.category_ids.include?(category.id), id: dom_id(category) %> 
        <%= label_tag dom_id(category), category.name %>
      <% end %>    
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :status, value: "Draft" %> 
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body, class: "redactor", id: "redactor" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :published_on %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :published_on %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Here is the portion that I am having trouble converting to formtastic specific code.  It comes from Ryan's screencast on [HABTM Checkboxes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes-revised).

```
<div class="field">
    <p>
      Categories:<br>
      <%= hidden_field_tag "post[category_ids][]", nil %>
      <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
        <%= check_box_tag "post[category_ids][]", category.id, @post.category_ids.include?(category.id), id: dom_id(category) %> 
        <%= label_tag dom_id(category), category.name %>
      <% end %>    
    </p>
  </div>
```

Here is the formcode that is in the admin/post.rb file for Active Admin.  If I use this I continue to get a no method error for category.  I know that the way it is currently listed is incorrect.

```
form do |f|
    f.inputs "Details" do
        f.input :blog, hint: "Select a blog"
        f.input :title, hint: "Enter blog post title"
        f.input :published_on, as: :date, include_blank: false, hint: "Select a date", :prompt => {:day => "Day", :month => "Month", :year => "Year"}, :start_year => Time.now.year
        f.input :status, as: :select, collection: ["Draft", "Published"], include_blank: false, hint: 'Select "Draft" to save and post later, and "Publish" to post now'

        f.input :categories, as: :check_boxes

        f.input :body, input_html: { class: "redactor", id: "redactor" }
    end
    f.buttons
end
```

If anyone has any input I am most appreciated.  I have looked at the formtastic documentation and watched Ryan's screencasts, but am still having issues converting.

Thanks!

### EDIT: ABLE TO RESOLVE-SOLUTION BELOW

I was able to make this work after getting a little more familiar with Formtastic and Active Admin.  Below is the relevant code in the form, show, and index views in Active Admin.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
index do
    column "Post Title", :title
    column :blog
    column :published_on
    column :status
    column "Category", :categories do |post|
        post.categories.collect { |cat|  cat.name }.join(", ")
    end
    default_actions
end 

show do
    h5 "Created by #{post.blog.name} on #{post.created_at.strftime('%B %-d, %Y')}"
    h5 "Categories: #{post.categories.collect { |cat|  cat.name }.join(", ")}"
    h5 "Current Status: #{post.status}"
    h5 "Published On Date: #{post.published_on.strftime('%B %-d, %Y')} - (will only be posted if marked with Publish as status)"
    div do
        simple_format post.body
    end
end

form do |f|
    f.inputs "Details" do
        f.input :blog, hint: "Select a blog"
        f.input :title, hint: "Enter blog post title"
        f.input :published_on, as: :date, include_blank: false, hint: "Select a date", :prompt => {:day => "Day", :month => "Month", :year => "Year"}, :start_year => Time.now.year
        f.input :status, as: :select, collection: ["Draft", "Published"], include_blank: false, hint: 'Select "Draft" to save and post later, and "Publish" to post now'
        f.input :categories, as: :check_boxes, collection: Category.all
        f.input :body, input_html: { class: "redactor", id: "redactor" }
    end
    f.buttons
end  
end
```

Comment: Was able to get this to work, see edits to the question under the initial post.

Comment: You can answer your own questions on stackoverflow and accept it yourself so that other can take advantage of it

Comment: It's nice to share this solution with the community . You can put the last edit in answer , it will be valuable in the future . Good luck with the app , Aaron .

Comment: Thanks guys for the heads up on answering my own questions. I actually tried to do so originally and something went wrong so I just edited the original question.  I've been able to answer my own question now and will accept it later on when I am able (seems that I have to wait 21 hours to do so).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to construct the Formtastic version as shown below.  It took a little more understanding of Formtastic and then making minor adjustments for Active Admin.

Below is the relevant code in the form, show, and index views in Active Admin.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
index do
    column "Post Title", :title
    column :blog
    column :published_on
    column :status
    column "Category", :categories do |post|
        post.categories.collect { |cat|  cat.name }.join(", ")
    end
    default_actions
end 

show do
    h5 "Created by #{post.blog.name} on #{post.created_at.strftime('%B %-d, %Y')}"
    h5 "Categories: #{post.categories.collect { |cat|  cat.name }.join(", ")}"
    h5 "Current Status: #{post.status}"
    h5 "Published On Date: #{post.published_on.strftime('%B %-d, %Y')} - (will only be posted if marked with Publish as status)"
    div do
        simple_format post.body
    end
end

form do |f|
    f.inputs "Details" do
        f.input :blog, hint: "Select a blog"
        f.input :title, hint: "Enter blog post title"
        f.input :published_on, as: :date, include_blank: false, hint: "Select a date", :prompt => {:day => "Day", :month => "Month", :year => "Year"}, :start_year => Time.now.year
        f.input :status, as: :select, collection: ["Draft", "Published"], include_blank: false, hint: 'Select "Draft" to save and post later, and "Publish" to post now'
        f.input :categories, as: :check_boxes, collection: Category.all
        f.input :body, input_html: { class: "redactor", id: "redactor" }
    end
    f.buttons
end  
end
```